# How can I design custom fluidic Tabs in android studio?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-xml, android-tablayout, android-customtabs

I want to design custom fluidic tabs in android studio. I which whenever user select any of the tabs then the whole layout should move with a good effect. I have attached an image for the question.

[Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Buv.jpg)

I want to have this design in which when an user clicks any of the tabs then user should see this custom fluidic tabs. As you see in the image that I have attached an image where it displays that when user in Recent tab then the black color layout is covered the tabs. Here I Know I have to use Tab layout or view pager, but how can I design in this way in XML...

[red color circle marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKJpX.jpg)